# Why doesn't htaccess redirect domain alias to a specific url?

Tags: htaccess

I have this which i can't get to work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainalias.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domainalias\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.maindomain.com/specific-url/ [R=301,L]
```

it doesn't redirect to /specific-url/
any ideas?

Comment: How does it fail?  Does it not redirect at all or does it redirect to the wrong thing?

Comment: sorry it doesn't redirect at all.

Comment: Those rewrite rules should cause redirects if they are put in the right place.  What file are you putting them in?   Are the alias domain and the main domain served out of the same folder currently?

Comment: Have you checked AllowOverride in your configuration??

Comment: and are these rules in a .htaccess file or embedded into httpd.conf?

Comment: these rules are in a .htaccess located var/www/vhosts/maindomain.com/.htaccess
@closetnoc how can i check AllowOverride in my config?

Comment: btw the other rules in .htaccess are working correctly.

These two lines are on top and work ok
RedirectMatch 301 \@login /__site/admin
Redirect 302 /visitors/register /tickets

Comment: Okay. If part of your .htaccess is working, you should not need to check your config file for AllowOverride. Occasionally, people will try and use .htaccess and forget to check the AllowOverride directive. For future info, it would be something like /etc/apache2/apache2.conf or /etc/apache2/sites-available/domain-name.tld.conf.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to redirect a user from an old domain to a new domain on a specific page,
 you can use this:

**======= update ========**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainalias\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://maindomain.com/specific-url/$1 [R,L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domainalias.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.maindomain.com/specific-url/ [R=301,L]
```

**========= ### =========**

You can also redirect using a meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.example.org/newpage.html">
```

Comment: no in my case they have registered a specific domainname just for a specific page. So i have created a domainalias but need to redirect to the specific page

Comment: Here, try this update @alex .

Comment: almost but i get a infinty loop which reads something like 
http://www.maindomain.com/specific-url/specific-url/specific-url/specific-url/specific-url/specific-url/specific-url/specific-url/

Comment: What happens if you change the 3rd line for this instead `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.maindomain.com/specific-url/ [L,R=301]`

Comment: Still a infinity loop :(

Comment: I've edited my answer, if the first one doesn't work, I think the second will.

Comment: @alex The (infinite) redirect loop was likely caused by a cached response, due to the _previous_ (before the edit) directive being incorrect. When testing redirects it is often preferable to test with 302 (temporary) redirects which are not cached by the browser. However, this code is essentially the same as the code in your question.